# What to do when "CrashOnCtrlScroll" doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows, freeze, bsod, crash, debug

You've tried to enable a [useful](https://superuser.com/questions/13899/why-does-windows-still-have-the-bsod-on-ctrlscrollscroll-feature) developer feature named [CrashOnCtrlScroll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard).

You then tried to trigger a crash. Unfortunately, no crash happened.

What can you try now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips. In case the tips don't help you, I also offer links to some possible workarounds.

#### PS/2 vs. USB

Make sure you created the "CrashOnCtrlScroll" value in the correct Registry key location.  There are different key locations for PS/2 vs. USB vs. Hyper-V keyboards.  Please see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard).

If you're not sure which location to use: It's okay to create the same value in all three locations.

#### Reboot first

You must reboot your machine in order to make the Registry setting take effect.

#### Use the rightmost Ctrl key

Before pressing Scroll lock twice, you must hold down the **rightmost** Ctrl key.

Do not use the other Ctrl key; it won't work.

#### Possible workarounds

If you've tried all three of the above tips, and you still can't trigger a crash, perhaps you could instead:

- [Force a system crash from a debugger.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-debugger)
- [Force a system crash with the power button.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-with-the-power-button)
- [Force a system crash from the command line.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/notmyfault)
- [Force a system crash using a non-maskable interrupt.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/client-management/generate-kernel-or-complete-crash-dump)
- [Create a dump file without a system crash.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/creating-a-dump-file-without-a-system-crash)
- Post a new question, either on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or here on Super User, to seek our advice.

#### Conclusion

This post is partially based on an [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581551/force-bsod-on-windows-8-1#27637012) by Mohit Jain.